# Ask guidance to make video web application

Tags: node.js, express, video, stream

I'm trying to make web application that can
upload file via 'html input file',
play video on certain html,
and seek time code where users want to play.

I want to make those features based on node.js and express.

I found some tutorials, but they are based on system file, not from user's input.

```
const { createServer } = require('http');
const {
  stat,
  createReadStream,
  createWriteStream
} = require('fs');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const fileName = '../../powder-day.mp4';
const fileInfo = promisify(stat);
const multiparty = require('multiparty');

const respondWithVideo = async (req, res) => {
  const { size } = await fileInfo(fileName);
  await console.log(fileInfo(fileName));
  const range = req.headers.range;
  if (range) {
    let [start, end] = range.replace(/bytes=/, '').split('-');
    start = parseInt(start, 10);
    end = end ? parseInt(end, 10) : size - 1;
    res.writeHead(206, {
       'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${size}`,
       'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
       'Content-Length': (end-start) + 1,
       'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
    })
    createReadStream(fileName, { start, end }).pipe(res);
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Length': size,
      'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
    });
    createReadStream(fileName).pipe(res);
  }
}

createServer((req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    let form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.on('part', (part) => {
      part.pipe(createWriteStream(`./${part.filename}`))
        .on('close', () => {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            res.end(`<h1>File uploaded: ${part.filename}</h1>`);
        })
    });
    form.parse(req);
  } else if (req.url === '/video') {
    respondWithVideo(req, res);
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end(`
      <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="/">
        <input type="file" name="upload-file" />
        <button>Upload File</button>
      </form>
    `);
  }

}).listen(3000, () => console.log('server running - 3000'));
```

Is there any guide to do stream video with buffer string, not from a system path?

please advise

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the regular video HTML5 video tag?  if your video is: `https://example.com/myvideo.mp4`

you can just append `#t=10,20` and the video will start at 10 seconds, and stop 10 seconds later (20 seconds into the video).

It would look like this:
`https://example.com/myvideo.mp4#t=10,20`

source: [HTML5 Rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/)